# How to connect ICU library with gcc in the Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, gcc, libraries, netbeans

I have downloaded the icu4c-61_1-Ubuntu16.04-x64.tgz from the http://site.icu-project.org/download/61#TOC-ICU4C-Download site. I do not see any installation instruction there. In my NetBeans C/C++ 'Ant Library Manager' the button 'New Library' and other fields are inactive - inaccessible. (In the NetBeans, C debugging works.)
 In the filesystem, is there a directory where the unpacked library should be placed and/or a file where the information should be added? Thanks!

Comment: @muru: Please consider if the icu.project.org is not worth our attention enough to get its tag, that I have proposed. In fact, I am only trying it, but their site is generally recommended for solving problems with different language text coding. I intended to describe the proposed tag later. Thanks!

Comment: Are the existing tags insufficient?

Comment: I feel the tag 'language' as too general and 'language-support' is described as 'the language support provided by Ubuntu'. I suggested the tag 'icu' as an analogy to the tag 'gcc' .

Comment: And I replaced that with [tag:libraries], which is sufficiently general enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the FAQ](http://userguide.icu-project.org/icufaq#TOC-How-do-I-install-the-binary-versions-of-ICU-):

> - For other platforms, the .tgz file unpacks to a "`/usr/local`" type hierarchy. For system-wide installation, you can unpack all of the
>     files into `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/include`, etc.
> - The configuration script `/usr/local/bin/icu-config`  or the similar Makefile include fragment `/usr/local/lib/icu/current/Makefile.inc`
>     can be used in building applications.

To extract the archive's `icu/usr/local` to `/usr/local`:

```
sudo tar zxvf icu4c-61_1-Ubuntu16.04-x64.tgz -C /usr/local ./icu/usr/local --strip-components=4
```

The `tar` options:

- `-C /usr/local`: to put the extracted files in `/usr/local`
- `./icu/usr/local`: to extract only the contents of `./icu/usr/local` of from the archive (skipping the mostly useless `readme.txt`)
- `--strip-components=4`: to extract the files, but remove the leading 4 components (`./icu/usr/local`) from the paths, since we're already extracting to `/usr/local`.

If you have used `pkg-config` before, `icu-config` seems to be a similar script.